# Probability with fair dice

Tags: probability, combinatorics

If you roll 5 standard 6 sided dies, what's the probability that you will get at least three 2s?

I imagine it would be 1 - P(0 twos) - P(1 two) - P(2 twos), but I don't know how to calculate the probability of these.

Comment: This looks like pretty standard bookwork. Is this for some subject, or even just for the purposes of your own study?

Comment: Hint: What's the probability of getting *anything but* a 2 on a single throw of the die?

Comment: A 2-second Google search would have saved you from a 15-second question typing effort: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/337689/if-you-roll-5-standard-six-sided-dice-whats-the-probability-that-you-get-at

Comment: Useful information is available on our site through [a search](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=binomial+dice).